# Java: How to know if TIFF image is Group4?

Tags: java, image, tiff

Is it possible to know if a TIFF image is Group4 using a JAVA program?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Oracle Jai Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/com/sun/media/jai/codec/TIFFEncodeParam.html) you could use `getCompression` method and check if your compression is equal to `COMPRESSION_GROUP4` (int).

Or you can try to use the RenderedOp and the TIFFDirectory fields:

```
RenderedOp tiffFile= JAI.create("fileload","C:/test/20060829105323B10506002500200000000011.tiff");

int comp = getCompression(tiffFile);

if(comp == COMPRESSION_GROUP4)
System.out.println("Compression is : GROUP4");
```

And for the getCompression custom method:

```
private static int getCompression(RenderedOp op) throws Exception {
int TAG_COMPRESSION = 259;
TIFFDirectory dir = (TIFFDirectory)op.getProperty("tiff_directory");
if(dir.isTagPresent(TAG_COMPRESSION)) {
TIFFField compField = dir.getField(TAG_COMPRESSION);
return compField.getAsInt(0);
}
return 0;
}
```

---

Update: to use a SeekableStream you need an ImageReader to avoid load exceptions.

```
Iterator readersIterator = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("tif");
ImageReader imageReader = (ImageReader)readersIterator.next();
ImageInputStream imageInputStream;
try {
imageInputStream = new FileImageInputStream(new File("C:/test/20060829105323B10506002500200000000011.tiff"));
imageReader.setInput(imageInputStream,false, true);

/* Take a input from a file */
FileSeekableStream fileSeekableStream;
fileSeekableStream = new FileSeekableStream(inputTifImagePath);

/* create ImageDecoder to count your pages from multi-page tiff */
ImageDecoder iDecoder = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff", fileSeekableStream, null);

/* count the number of pages inside the multi-page tiff */
int pageCount = iDecoder.getNumPages();

/* use first for loop to get pages one by one */
for(int page = 0; page < pageCount; page++){
/* get image metadata for each page */
IIOMetadata imageMetadata = imageReader.getImageMetadata(page);

/*
 * The root of all the tags for this image is the IFD (Image File Directory).
 * Get the IFD from where we can get all the tags for the image.
 */
TIFFDirectory ifd = TIFFDirectory.createFromMetadata(imageMetadata);

/* Create a Array of TIFFField*/
TIFFField[] allTiffFields = ifd.getTIFFFields();

/* use second for loop to get all field data */
for (int i = 0; i < allTiffFields.length; i++) {
TIFFField tiffField = allTiffFields[i];

/* name of property */
String nameOfField = tiffField.getTag().getName();

/* Type of property (optional) */
String typeOfField = TIFFField.getTypeName(tiffField.getType());                                 

/* Tag no. of the property (optional) */
int numberOfField = tiffField.getTagNumber(); }// we are looking for 259, jump optional step out of loop


TIFFField compField = ifd.getField(259);

/* Value of Property*/
int valueOfField = compField.getAsInt(0);
```

Let me know if it works so I can update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried it and I've got an exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FileLoad - Parameter value`s class (java.io.File) is not an instance of the parameter class (java.lang.String) for parameter "filename".

Comment: @HoussamLahrach code edited. If wont work try loading the File separately, then retrieve the path with getCanonicalPath().

Comment: Thank you very much, that modification corrects the error, now I have another exception:  java.lang.Object cannot be cast to com.sun.media.jai.codec.TIFFDirectory

Comment: @HoussamLahrach maybe it prefers JAI.create("tiff","C:/test/20060829105323B10506002500200000000011.tiff"); with "tiff" in place of "fileload". Give it a try.

Comment: Thank you again, but also the same error as the first one,  TIFF - Parameter value`s class (java.lang.String) is not an instance of the parameter class (com.sun.media.jai.codec.SeekableStream) for parameter "stream".

Comment: Thanks again, the method createFromMetaData doesn't exist and also getName ( tiffField.getTag().getName() ) and getTypeName ( TIFFField.getTypeName(tiffField.getType()))

Comment: @HoussamLahrach check your java libraries http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/javadoc/1.1/com/sun/media/imageio/plugins/tiff/TIFFDirectory.html#createFromMetadata(javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata)

Comment: I should import com.sun.media.imageio.plugins.tiff.TIFFDirectory instead of com.sun.media.jai.codec.TIFFDirectory ??

Answer (score 1):

Thank you. My new code is as follows

```
public static void TesterImage() throws Exception
{
    Iterator readersIterator = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("tif");
    ImageReader imageReader = (ImageReader)readersIterator.next();
    ImageInputStream imageInputStream;
    try {
        File file = new File("/Users/houssam/Pictures/statue.tiff");
        imageInputStream = new FileImageInputStream(file);
        imageReader.setInput(imageInputStream);

        FileSeekableStream fileSeekableStream;
        fileSeekableStream = new FileSeekableStream(file.getCanonicalPath());

        //ImageDecoder iDecoder = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff", fileSeekableStream, null);
        IIOMetadata imageMetadata = imageReader.getImageMetadata(0);
        TIFFDirectory ifd = TIFFDirectory.createFromMetadata(imageMetadata);
        if(getCompression(ifd)==COMPRESSION_GROUP4)
            System.out.println("Est de type Group4");
        else
            System.out.println("N'est pas de type Group4");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
static int TAG_COMPRESSION = 259;
public static int getCompression(TIFFDirectory ifd) throws Exception {

    TIFFField[] allTiffFields = ifd.getTIFFFields();

    for (int i = 0; i < allTiffFields.length; i++) {
        TIFFField tiffField = allTiffFields[i];

        String nameOfField = tiffField.getTag().getName();

        String typeOfField = TIFFField.getTypeName(tiffField.getType());

        System.out.println("Le nom est:"+nameOfField);
        System.out.println("Le type est:"+typeOfField);
        int numberOfField = tiffField.getTagNumber(); // we are looking for 259, jump optional step out of loop
        System.out.println(numberOfField + " Is The Number");
        if(numberOfField==TAG_COMPRESSION)
        {
            TIFFField compField = ifd.getTIFFField(TAG_COMPRESSION);
            int valueOfField = compField.getAsInt(0);
            return valueOfField;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well done! Please add this code to your first post explaining this is your working code (built on my suggestions, so people can find both the easy and the trouble way...)